# Optimizing Nested Loop Performance in Pandas DataFrame for Round-Robin Comparison

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, nested-loops

I have a code snippet that utilizes nested loops to compare each item in a Pandas DataFrame (data) with every other item in the same DataFrame, resulting in a round-robin comparison. However, the code's execution time is excessively long due to the complexity of the functions involved. The outer loop alone takes around 20 minutes, and given the size of my dataset (13k+ items), the estimated completion time is around 180 days.

Here's the existing code:

```
temp=[]
for _,a in data.iterrows():
    total=0
    for index,b in tqdm(data.iterrows()):
        results=check(a['content'],b['content'])
        left=funcleft(a['content'],results)
        total=total+left
    average=total/len(data)
```

I have made optimizations within the functions themselves, but I'm wondering if there is an alternative approach that avoids the need for nested loops. Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same result while leveraging the capabilities of Pandas dataframes? Any suggestions for improvement would be greatly appreciated.

Note: The functions check() and funcleft() perform complex operations on the contents of the items being compared.

Comment: There are definitely things we can do for this, but if you can generate some fake data taking a minute or so in a working example, it gives us an easier starting point.

Comment: @Carbon What specific data you need? data is a single column dataframe of strings, check() function returns a string based on relation between a and b (this is simple function and doesn't take much time), funcleft()  is a complex function which has all data (dataframe) and eliminates rows fro data dataframe based on a and results and returns number of rows left. I have to calculate average

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your problem may not be able to benefit from pandas vectorization, you simply have a list of strings and you want to compare each item with all other items based on some custom logic, here is a simplified version (should be slightly faster too) :

```
from tqdm import tqdm

# your list of strings
str_list = data['content'].to_list()
n_items = len(str_list)

for a in str_list:
    total = sum(funcleft(a, check(a, b)) for b in tqdm(str_list))
    average = total / n_items
    # rest of logic
```

I suggest you provide a small example with the check() and funcleft() functions, there might be some room for optimization in their implementation itself.